# Rotating symbols with data frame in ArcGIS Pro?

Tags: symbology, arcgis-pro, rotate

I have a Map Series in ArcGIS Pro that was imported from ArcMap (with Data Driven Pages) to produce several different orientations. In Pro, symbols are not rotating with the data frame-- they are always oriented North up. Symbols with a rotation value in the attribute table are being rotated by these values, but nothing is rotated with the data frame.

Is there something I need to do (along the lines of checking "rotate symbols with data frame in Utilities for ArcMap) to get this to work?

I am totally new to ArcGIS Pro.

Comment: Despite being at version 2.1, Pro is still missing quite a few features that ArcMap has, this may be one of them.

Answer (score 4):

Symbol rotation for point markers is defined when you click on the symbol and view its properties. Under Angle alignment is a drop box showing Display and Map. You can augment the rotation by defining which one you want.

This is set per individual symbol, so the process goes like this:
Click the symbol in the Contents Pane (Or open the Symbology pane and click the symbol)
You'll see the Gallery and Properties tabs. Click Properties
There are three tabs under Properties: Symbol / Layers / Structure. Click Symbol.
Next are two drop-downs: Appearance and Halo. Click Appearance.
There you will see Angle Alignment.

Display - Point symbol is rotated according to your screen.
Map - Point symbol is rotated according to the data frame (map properties)

Comment: If you have many symbols in one feature class and want to change them all at once, you can also click 'More' on the main Symbology Tab, 'Format All Symbols', then under Properties, open the Appearance drop-down, and change the Angle Alignment to 'Map'.

Answer (score -2):

In the "Map Properties" dialog box and in the "Label" menu, there is an option to "Rotate point and polygon labels when map is rotated".

I'm not sure if this is what you meant by "symbols", but it works for labels and point icons.

[image]